# Why do enumerated lists become more compact when using `columns` with `parskip` loaded (beamer)?

Tags: beamer, columns, parskip

When I use `columns` environment to include enumerate items, the presence of `parskip` will force enumerated items to become more compact.

[image]

The output above will not be the same if `parskip` is disabled.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}


\usecolortheme{rose}

    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=black}

\useoutertheme[]{split}

\useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \setbeamersize{text margin left=2mm, text margin right=2mm}

    \newlength{\sidebarWidth}
    \setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.2\paperwidth}

    \setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}



\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{fvextra}
\let \verb \Verb



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    This is an example of \verb{columns} environment used to include a side figure

    \begin{columns}

        \column[t]{0.5\textwidth}

            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item
                \item Item
                \item Item
            \end{itemize}

        \column[t]{0.5\textwidth}

            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

    \end{columns}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item
        \item Item
        \item Item
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would not use the `parskip` package with beamer.

Comment: Maybe to tackle the underlying problem: why do you want to use `parskip` with beamer?

Comment: I use `parskip` to allow for adjusting `\parfillskip` to impose minimum white space after the last line of a paragraph and the next one, which seemed to provide better output in most other document classes. I realize that I do not need `parskip` for beamer but I just want to understand what exactly caused the issue with `beamer`. Since I already knew what causes compact lists in my `beamer` presentations, you could say it is rather a curiosity than some real trouble I am trying to deal with

Comment: The issue is that beamer internally uses minipages for columns, which don't adhere to pasrkip of the rest of the document. You would have the same issue with most other document classes as well.